# Connect microSD card with your PC folder via Wi-Fi only

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, sd-card, file-transfer, dropbox

Suppose you sit in an office where you have high speed wi-fi internet connection to which you can connect your android mobile phone. On your office pc you have some downloaded videos , pictures etc. that you want to transfer to your mobile micro SD card. Now at home where you dont have internet connection, but you want to see those videos and pictures.

Unfortunately you don't have data card cable or you don't want to use data card.

Is there any application for doing such stuff

[idea is similar to dropbox app, but you should have active internet connection everywhere]

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.**

I will explain the setup I am using for past couple of years over various devices.

I use [Swiftp](http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/downloads/list) in android to make a FTP server. This project is abandoned now, but the apk works on 4.2 jellybean (not sure about 4.3). Or as an alternative you can setup a FTP server via most file managers these days, eg [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer). Setup a username and password for the FTP server and start FTP server in the phone.

Then I use [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php) in the PC (which is on same Wi-Fi network as the phone) and connect with the credentials to the FTP server set up on the android phone/tablet.

This will enable you to transfer files from PC to phone and viceversa.

**Option 2.**

Use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). Simple to setup and easy to use. I will recommend this over FTP server.

Good Luck.